# Strange Custom Actions

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, installation

I've just created msi installation package for my application using Setup Project. I've used custom action for commit, rollback, unistall. 
I opened package with Orca tool and navigate to the table "Custom Action". . i found some strange custom action:

```
ACTION:  DIRCA_CheckFX
TYPE:  1
SOURCE:  MSVBDPCADLL
TARGET:  CheckFX

ACTION:  VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions
TYPE:  1
SOURCE:  MSVBDPCADLL
TARGET:  VsdLaunchConditions

ACTION:  DIRCA_TARGETDIR
TYPE:  307
SOURCE:  TARGETDIR
TARGET:  [ProgramFilesFolder][Manufacturer]\[ProductName]
```

**Please explain to me what these system actions do.**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

DIRCA_CheckFX checks to see if the appropriate version of the .Net framework is installed.

VSDCA_VsdLaunchConditions executes the custom action MSVBDPCA.DLL, which has functionality for interacting with IIS (it is called the URL Convert custom action, probably because that's what its initial functionality was). Note that in non-VB installs, the custom action in DPCA.DLL.

DIRCA_TARGETDIR sets the target directory for the installation.